# cloud foundry "incorrect usage" error when trying to push node.js app on windows

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push an app to cloud foundry. I have gotten this to work in the past, but this is the first time I am doing it after installing cloudfoundry manually.

After navigating to my folder with the file that launches my app, called server.js, I type the following command:

```
cf push --command "node server.js"
```

I get the response:

```
paul@PAUL_LAPTOP /c/users/paul/projects2/meadowlark (master)
$ cf push --command "node server.js"
Incorrect Usage.
```

no details are provided, which makes this very hard to debug. I used this exact same syntax before and it worked fine. Any idea what might be causing this error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use '-c' instead of '--command' and do not use double quotes ("). Try fol
cf push -c node server.js

Comment: @ neeraj, thank you, it got rid of the "incorrect usage" error. However, I am now getting an error that says "sever code: 400, error code: 170003, message: "an app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack". I will look around and if this error is completely unrelated I will accept your answer

Comment: it turned out to be that I wasmissing a package.json file. thanks for your help!